# React: How to import images dynamically depending on environment variables?

Tags: reactjs

I need to import a different logo image depending on the process environemnt variable.

```js
import logo from `./assets/flavour/${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_DIR}/logo.png`;
```

This raises an error: `Unexpected token error`.

How can I accomplish that? Is that possible?

Comment: see if this help https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotenv

Comment: Can you kindly add the code snippets of where you are trying to use these logos?

Comment: `key = "image1" or "image2" => ${process.env.[key]} ` make sure the name of the variable matches the name in your `.env` file. Maybe use an enumeration or something similar to enforce matching names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using dynamic imports or webpack.

### Dynamic imports

Your import will look something like this:

```
let logo;
import(`./assets/flavour/${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_DIR}/logo.png`).then((module) => {
  logo = module.default; // <= base64 image
});

...

<img src={logo} alt="logo" />
```

But in this way you will get the desired `logo` value only at the next render and if `logo` was loaded before.

Therefore, there is the option to use this `useState` and imports within our functional components:

```js
export const Logo = () => {
  const [logo, setLogo] = useState('');

  import(`./assets/flavour/${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_DIR}/logo.png`).then((module) => {
    setLogo(module.default);
  });

  return (
    <img src={logo} />
  );
};
```

If you have a lot of such images import, then this component can be rewritten so that it is reusable:

```js
export const Image = ({path, alt}) => {
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState('');

  import(path).then((module) => {
    setImageSrc(module.default);
  });

  return (
    <img src={imageSrc} alt={alt} />
  );
};
```

### Wepback aliases

The second option that came to my mind is try using Webpack aliases. To do this add to your `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = (env) => ({
  // ...
  resolve: {
    // ...
    alias: {
      '@assets': path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'flavour', env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_DIR),
    },
  },
  // ...
})
```

And then use in your code:

```js
import logo from `@assets/logo.png`;
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works, but I have still a problem:

If I set the path as a string it works:

import("./img/logo.png").then((module) => {
    setImageSrc(module.default);
});

If I use a variable to set the path it doesn't works:
(Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module)

const path = "./img/logo.png";
import(path).then((module) => {
    setImageSrc(module.default);
});

Do you know why?

Comment: @FabioDev, perhaps the path to the picture is incorrect, if you show the file structure of the project or the project on the github, then I will try to help you

Comment: Solved.

I put both a string and a variable, inside import function:

Only partially dynamic statement are allowed for import().

Answer (score 1):

I did a write up on how I managed it, along with an example:
[Dynamic Enviroment Based Imports in React / Javascript / Node](https://github.com/augustkimo/Dynamic-Enviroment-Based-Imports-in-React-and-Javascript). You can customize this solution to meet your needs.

My solution uses a python script to set the targets and change the imports.

`npm run target-ios`

```
Modifying imports to match the specified platform: ios

Line modified in file: ./app/components/profiles/Avatar.tsx
Org: import PlatformAvatar from "./Avatar.webandroid"; // !dynamic-import options=["webandroid", "ios"]
New: import PlatformAvatar from "./Avatar.ios"; // !dynamic-import options=["webandroid", "ios"]
```